# Using dd to restore multiple partitions from multiple image files to same destination drive

Tags: dd, images

I want to use `dd` command to create image file(s) from a source machine then extract it using `dd` to a destination machine.

But the catch is that mount points `/` and `/home` are on separate partitions on separate drives.

```
# /dev/sda1 is mounted at /
# and /dev/sdb1 is mounted at /home
# boot to a live cd and run:

dd if=/dev/sda1 | gzip -c > backup_root.img.gz
dd if=/dev/sdb1 | gzip -c > backup_home.img.gz

# switch to a target system, boot to a live cd
# create partitions of equal size to their source.
# then

gunzip -c backup_root.img.gz | dd of=/dev/sda1
gunzip -c backup_home.img.gz | dd of=/dev/sda2

# can I do this given source images are made from different drives?
```

Will this work? (I forgot about /boot and swap partitions but they should be extracted to destination machine too)

Someone suggested just using `gzip/gunzip` without `dd`:

```
gzip - </dev/sda1 >backup.root.img.gz
gunzip - <backup.root.img.gz >/dev/sda1'
```

Comment: No.  The dd command is image copy & is an exact copy including all empty space. It is for same size drive to another drive of same or larger size. Better to just use rsync and copy data. And you really should use your normal backup to restore. Better to use rsync, not dd
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331348/can-i-use-dd-to-back-up-a-mounted-partition & http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders

Answer (score 0):

1. The `dd` indeed does nothing in your commands. It is useful if you need block-level access, but since you are using `gzip`/`gunzip` anyway, you can drop it.
2. If you boot from a live CD, make sure `sda1` and `sdb1` are unmounted before you make the image. Any activity in the filesystem that goes on in parallel with you making the copy can potentially cause trouble.
3. If the partitions are of exactly equal size, it will work. Otherwise, you may overwrite following partitions. Double check the size when creating them.
4. Again, make sure the partitions are unmounted before you do the copy.